# use rename command to batch rename the files

Tags: linux, shell

I tried to just keep the numbers in the square brackets and the file extensions.
so the files below:

```
【004】ssd水电费.txt
【006】佛山市，地方cd2.txt
【022】风sf.pdf
```

I'd like to be:

```
004.txt
006.txt
022.pdf
```

or just like

```
4.txt
6.txt
22.pdf
```

I know the 'rename 's/old-exp/new-exp' command and a little bit regex, however I could not found a way to match the regex what i expected.

I tried `rename 's/[\u4e00-\u9eff]+//' *` to replace the Chinese chars but not work.

Comment: Maybe something like `rename 's/\[(\d\d\d)\].*/$1.txt/' *.txt`? (Try with `-n` for dry-run first).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like the following:

```
rename 'tr/A-Za-z0-9.//cd; s/^(\d+).*(\.[a-z]+)$/$1$2/' *
```

(You'll want to use `-n` first to test that it does what you want.)

That removes all characters from the file name other than `A-Za-z0-9.` and then pulls out only the extension and the digits at the beginning.

The reason the Unicode match doesn't work is because `rename` uses byte strings, not Unicode strings, since not all Unix paths are guaranteed to be valid Unicode. Therefore, unless you have to, it's easier to simply filter out the byte values that you don't want rather than than convert them to Unicode.